# Loading .pfx to gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, certificate, pfx

I am trying to test e-mail encryption using between my standard e-mail service and Gmail. I can’t figure out how to load  .pfx file in Gmail.

Regards,
Janusz

Comment: Seems like people are having luck renaming `*.pfx` to `*.p12`.  This is from https://groups.google.com/g/office-talk-for-android/c/uJj--LoqUg8

Comment: But what are the steps to load the file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get `*.p12` certificate from Google:

1. Open the project, go to APIs & auth > Credentials
2. Click on Create new Client ID, and select Service account and P12 key.
3. Click on Create Client ID to download it.

To upload a certificate in Gmail:

1. From your Gmail inbox, choose Settings.
2. Click the Accounts and Import tab.
3. In the Send mail as area, click Edit info. ...
4. Click Upload a personal certificate.
5. Select the certificate and click Open. ...
6. Enter the password and click Add certificate.

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/6374496?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-upload-certificates

Comment: That where the problem is. I have Settings but under that Setting I don't have another Settings (I have some "See all settings", "Density", "Theme" and so on) so I don't know how to get to the "Accounts" tab. Could you please point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Looks like Google change the setting menu.  I will correct the answer.

Comment: The steps are directly from Google.  You may want to ask https://support.google.com/a/thread/new?source=need_more_help for more help.